# My question was turned into a community wiki - should/can I still pick a best answer?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, best-practices, accepted-answer

[A question I asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55353/is-there-a-good-bridge-between-high-school-math-and-the-more-advanced-topics) was recently turned into a community wiki question. Ok, no problem. I understand why that decision was made. Before that was done however, I was contemplating which of the answers I'd received should be marked "best answer". Now that my question is CW, I note that the button to mark as best is still available to me, although I don't know if it would work if I clicked it.

I use a number of Stack Exchange sites regularly, but this is the first time one of my questions has been wiki-ized, so I'm curious: **Can I still pick a best answer, even though it's a community wiki question? *Should* I?** Will it affect my acceptance rate if I don't?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember: accepting an answer on any of the StackExchange site is not so much an endorsement of that answer being objectively the *best*, but that answer being the *most helpful to you*, the person who posted the original query. So with that in mind, you should feel free to accept an answer, even though the question is Community Wiki.

On the other hand, while we do encourage people to accept answers for *non*-CW questions, we do not push as hard for you to accept an answer to a CW question. While it is always up to you whether you mark any answer as accepted, for non-CW questions the expectation is that you *should* mark one, if there is an answer that answers your question. For CW questions there is no such expectation: even if there is an answer that precisely answers your question, we are not going to push you one way or the other on the issue of whether you should accept an answer. So it is really just up to you.

Lastly, about acceptance rate: you can consult my answer to [How is acceptance rate calculated?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2655/1543) for the general algorithm. To answer your specific question: CW questions do not factor in the computation for acceptance rates.

Answer (score 10):

You should pick the one that most helps you, I'd say.

But do not do it too soon, for otherwise you only diminish the chances of people adding other answers.